# Where to find reviews?

Tags: android

I would like to develop an Android application. In that app, I would like to get the reviews of restaurants, pubs, tourism places, etc. from a specific location.

Is there any API to get these kinds of reviews?

Comment: Perhaps, have a look at Google Prediction API's - http://code.google.com/apis/predict/

Comment: This really isn't an Android issue, but I'm at a loss of what would be a better existing tag for it.

Comment: Take a look at using open Intents, for instance OpenTable has some, so it should be super trivial to add some of the functionality of OpenTable (for restaurants reviews and restaurant reservations) to your Android application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try Yelp developer resources to build something.

Here is the URL http://www.yelp.com/developers